# How to add a space after a diacritical mark only if no space came after it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using this regular expression to remove an Arabic diacritical mark from a subtitle file, How it could be modified to add a space after the diacritical mark only if no space came after the diacritical mark? I'm using python 2.7.

```
file_content = re.sub(u'\u0651', '', file_content)
```

like

أعطني المفكّ، الآن

I need to add space after ّ

to be

أعطني المفكّ ، الآن

Comment: Could you update your question with a couple of lines. That would improve the ability to help you.

Comment: @philip I have updated my question.

Comment: You should really do what you can to migrate to Python 3 as soon as possible. The old version will go out of support soon, and the community is already visibly less eager to offer answers and support for questions about the old version.

Comment: For those who - like me - are not able to read Arabic, the space appears to be after المفكّ where the last character has the diacritic (remember this is right-to-left text, so the last character is the leftmost).

Comment: @tripleee I'm trying to modify an add on that supports both python 3 and 2 but I'm using it with a stable version of a program that supports python 2 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular expressions you could search for all occurrences of your dictation mark that has no space immediately after it:

```py
file_content = re.sub(u'\u0651[^ ]', '\u0651 ', file_content)
```

`[^ ]` would mean any character that is not a simple whitespace.

`\S` would also be possible instead of `[^ ]`, since it would match anything that is not a space.

---

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

> [] Used to indicate a set of characters.
>
> Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing the set. **If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters that are not in the set will be matched. For example, [^5] will match any character except '5',** and [^^] will match any character except '^'. ^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the set.

`\S`

> Matches any character which is not a whitespace character. This is the opposite of \s. If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of [^ \t\n\r\f\v].

Comment: The space should go *after* it, though. Maybe look at `\S` as well, though then you'll have to use a lookahead or capture the non-space character into the substitution.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answered my question.